# event not returning expected data

Tags: web3js, events

When I start my app I listen for posts from the latest block. After a post has been made I'm supposed to return author (address), title (string) and an id (uint).

But what I get in the author and id field is always wrong:

```
returnValues:
Result {
'0': '0xc56d6494E13A21c9fe6959DC3c0F2e95317ec52d',
'1': 'something',
'2': '1404800390165147213522565871758984e835369099666681',
author: '0xc56d6494E13A21c9fe6959DC3c0F2e95317ec52d',
title: 'something',
id: '1404800390165147213522565871758984835369099666681' }
```

The event listener:

```
postListener = () => {
    web3s.eth.getBlock('latest').then((latestBlock) => {
        contract.events.Posted({
            filter: {
                author: addressList,
            },
            fromBlock: latestBlock.number,
        }).on('data', function (event) {
            console.log({ event });
        }).on('error', console.error);
    });
}
```

ABI:

```
{
    "anonymous": false,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "indexed": true,
            "name": "author",
            "type": "address"
        },
        {
            "indexed": false,
            "name": "title",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "indexed": true,
            "name": "id",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ],
    "name": "Posted",
    "type": "event"
}
```

What I expect is something like:

```
author: '0xF6116D9AAE20eb8ca881D2D69a0456519Ae524f9',
title: 'something',
id: '10578'
```

The source of the contract can be found here: https://github.com/WhaleCoinOrg/WhaleNet/blob/followers/contracts/WhaleNetworkV4.sol

Answer (score 0):

My "solution" was to delete my `node_modules` folder and reinstall them all.

Comment: This didn't working for me